# Laravel + JWT - User Not Found

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm currently implementing JWT in my project to support an API of sorts. This API is only available for a specific `model`. This model works correctly using the custom guard I've declared when I want to log it in, I've ensured the contracts and authenticatable traits have been properly applied, yet the `->byId` method always fails. Here's my code:

```
namespace App;

class Customer extends Model implements Authenticatable {

    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
```

In my `jwt.php` file, I've told it to use my custom model:

```
'user' => \App\Customer::class,
```

When I execute:

```
JWTAuth::fromUser($customer);
```

I receive a proper token.

I then use Postman to check this by passing it with the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header. The token is correctly set.

For subsequent requests to my protected route, I then attempt to authenticate the user in this way:

```
$token = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

`->authenticate()` always fails.

The reason it fails is due to this:

```
 if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) {
        return false;
 }
```

This always returns false.

However, resolving the `id` from the `$id = $this->getPayload($token)->get('sub');` call does provide me with the valid ID for this particular Customer. Further, the model is actually a traditional model, where the PK is the `id` column, and my identifier is set correctly:

```
'identifier' => 'id',
```

Why is the `EloquentUserAdapter` not able to resolve an instance of my `Customer`?

I've scoured Google and have attempted a variety of fixes, but nothing has come to fruition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I've dumped the SQL query that was executed, and the table it attempts to reference is my default User model, it is not my custom model. Why is that?

**Update 2**
The `tymon.jwt.provider.user` singleton bound to the UserInterface correctly references my custom model:

```
return $app['tymon.jwt.provider.user'];
```

Provides:

```
EloquentUserAdapter {#849
    #user: Customer {#850
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #table: "customers"
```

**Update 3**

In booting the JWT User provider, it knows which model I want to use:

```
$model = $app->make($this->config('user'));
```

Yields:

```
Customer {#1040
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #table: "customers"
```

Comment: try to clear config cache
artisan config:clear

Comment: @michail1982 I did try that, nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the problem.

Under the hood, JWT will use your model to generate a token. However, it does not pass that model to illuminate's Auth Manager, which it will use when attempting to verify the model.

For this purpose, I needed to create my own AuthAdapter and Model (Customer) Adapter:

The `AuthAdapter` should extend JWT's `AuthInterface`

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\AuthInterface;

class CustomerAuthAdapter extends AuthInterface {
```

Of course it must implement all of the same methods that the `AuthInterface` does.

Within the `byCredentials` and `byId` method of this function, you should log your user into the application. This will ensure that later when JWT want to parse the token and call `->authenticate()`, that your user will be available as `Auth::guard('customer')->user()`. For your purposes, you may not care about the custom guard and can just use `Auth::user()` (or auth()->user()).

You will also need to provide your own `EloquentAdapter`, which extends the JWT `UserInterface`:

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\User\UserInterface;

class EloquentCustomerAdapter implements UserInterface
```

In this file, it's imperative to inject your `Customer` model (for my example) dependency into the constructor:

```
 public function __construct(Customer $user)
```

Then update your `jwt.php` file in `/config`

```
'user' => '\Path\To\My\EloquentAdapter'

'auth => '\Path\To\My\AuthAdapter'
```

Then you'll be able to authenticate your token `byId` or `byCredentials` against your `Customer` model (or whatever custom model you wish to use)